# How can I measure the current, in a precise way, using an arduino?

Tags: arduino, current-measurement, current-source

I designed a low noise current source for a project in my university and I would like to know if it is possible to measure the provided current using an arduino and a LCD.

Comment: Use something like an ACS712 in addition.

Comment: `I would like to know if it is possible ... `. Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @H.Puc thanks, I didn't think about sth like that. Won't it add some noise at the output of my current source?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. However, ready-made devices are available for this purpose. Why not just use one of those like a current meter. What is your advantage of making a current meter yourself if not for education purposes that is.

Comment: @JavierGarcia if you are going to ask questions about noise you need to give more technical details of the current source and its noise levels.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the current, or do you also need to be able to see the noise at the same time?  The Arduino only has a 10 bit ADC.   You can't really measure small variations in a large value with it.

Comment: Is the current source at the top or at the bottom or in between? How much current does is source (range)? How much is the "low noise"?

Comment: @JRE Yes I think 10 bits it is not enough because I want a resolution of +-0.01mA with the current going up to 200mA. Then I though about adding a ADC before the arduino. I don't need to see the noise, but I want it low enough in order to get the current stable for that resolution. I don't know if all that I am saying make perfect sense, but I'm still in my bachelors so no much experience yet.

Comment: Oops. You just changed everything. .01 mA on a 200 mA full scale is one part in 200,000. I'm sure you can convert that to binary, and this will tell you how many bits you need in an ADC. Can you get that many bits in an Arduino? If not, then you definitely need a separate ADC.

Answer (score 4):

Arduino has inbuilt 10-bit ADC which can measure voltage from 0-5 V. If the current to be measured is passing through a known resistor R, hook the nodes of the resistor to two analog pins on the arduino. Use analogread() function to find the two node voltages. Calculate the difference to get the voltage drop across the resistor. Then I = V/R. Calculate it and print the value on the LCD.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, it's possible. You have to do it in two steps. First read the current as voltage using analogue pins and second draw it on a display.

There are few ways to read the current. Build it yourself or buy a shield.
[Shield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ina219-current-sensor-breakout/wiring)

The second sollution is use a differential OPA and a shunt resistor. This step requieres some calculations. I'm, adding you a good guide. [Guide](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279404)

As for the second step there are a lot of modules you can buy or you can do it yourself with any display and digital lines from arduino.

Hope this helps you. Good luck.